# How does more than one hex-digit in a hex-escape work in the grammar?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, escaping

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hkhae3sw.aspx) page a valid hex-sequence is `\x` followed by one digit only. How does `\x61` can work? rather, I expected the output be  `\x6` decoded and the `1` value itself into string like `"\x61"` but it output the `\x61` decoded. What am I missing?

Comment: Did they mean one byte? Like in percent encoding hex values in URLs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Binary_data?

Comment: Valid hex sequences have no specified limit in C.  C11 §6.4.4.4 1

Comment: @bytefire: I'm not sure if I get you but I mean not in URLs but in a C-string.

Comment: @chux: It does make sense but not necessary answer this question. What I'm asking(basically) is why the documentation and implementation doesn't match (from what I understood).

Comment: 1) Rather than bury the key part about the doc that you are questioning as a link, better to state it in your post.  2) My _comment_ was not meant to _answer_ the question, else I would have posted an _answer_.  3) @pdw answers it well 4) `\xA\xB`, `\xAB` are both OK.  the first is 2 hexadecimal-escape-sequences, the second is 1 hexadecimal-escape-sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the second expansion. The full definition is:

```
hexadecimal-escape-sequence:
    "\x" hexadecimal-digit 
     hexadecimal-escape-sequence hexadecimal-digit
```

So the minimal escape sequence is "\x" followed by a single digit, but you can extend the escape sequence by adding as many digits as you like.

Comment: From what I understood this second expansion does allow this work: `\xA\xB` but not `\xAB` correct?

Comment: No, the second expansion says that if you have an hex escape sequence (such as "\xA") and an hex digit ("B"), then the concatenation "\xAB" is also a valid hex escape sequence.

Comment: That's it. I was thinking I needed a "\x" before every hexadecimal-digit